# Method references in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, method-reference

I am attempting to use a Java 8 feature in Android Studio. Specifically method references. To be even more specific, a reference to an instance method of a particular object. To use the wording the [Oracle docs page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

My offending code is this. The relevant methods are initTablet, and doStuff which is a dummy method I'm using to figure this out.

```
public class SettingsPresenter {

    SettingsFragment fragment;
    DeviceModel deviceModel;

    public SettingsPresenter(SettingsFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        Context appContext = fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        deviceModel = new DeviceModel(appContext);
    }

    public boolean showTabletInit() {
        Map<String, String> creds = deviceModel.getServerCredentials();
        if (creds.get("pname").isEmpty() || creds.get("pvalue").isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int doStuff() {
        return 1;
    }

    public void initTablet(String tokenId) {
        Log.d("debug", tokenId);
        deviceModel.initServerCredentials(tokenId, this::doStuff);
    }
}
```

The error is being highlighted at

```
deviceModel.initServerCredentials(tokenId, this::doStuff);
```

with "this::doStuff" showing the cannot resolve method error.

I followed the steps [Android Java 8 support page](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html). And so have the following values in my Project Structure:

- Compile Sdk Version: API 25: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat)
- Build Tools Version 26.0.2
- Source Compatibility 1.8
- Target Compatibility 1.8

My build.grandle looks like this

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hoistiq.machinelog"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is all on Android Studio 3.0.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case for using/trying that feature. In easy words, you want to reference something when you are away **outside** class(not inside). If you want to reference some method inside class just call it simply like `dostuff` or  `this.dostuff`. If you want to practice this, you can do something like following:

```
SettingsPresenter MyPresenter = new SettingsPresenter(A_Fragment);
deviceModel.initServerCredentials(tokenId, MyPresenter.doStuff);
```

The Method `dostuff` is not static, so i define an object. You can do it with a static method and just class name.

Comment: Still an issue with the same bug. I created a simple POJO called Tester with a method doStuff.

    Tester t = new Tester();
    deviceModel.initServerCredentials(tokenId, t::doStuff);

Comment: ;(  I find the problem. The problem is that you think it calls `dostuff` and return 1 but it doesn't do that. it is just a reference to method itself. In the example from [ORACLE webpage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), the `sort` method takes a function as second parameter. Do you get what i mean?

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. I didn't expect dostuff to return 1. I was trying to pass the reference. After playing with it some more, I discovered that the method signature of the receiving method deviceModel.initServerCredentials did not have the appropriate type information to receive the method reference. Making a correction to Consumer<String> doStuff made the error go away. So misleading error at worst, but more likely I just needed to learn more. Thanks. I've up voted your answer, but my reputation is too low for it to be recorded apparently.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't mind(about up vote). Glad to help a misunderstanding take away.